# Looking to create an efficient way to display a non-binary tree structure

Tags: python-3.x, genetic-programming

I'm working on a creating a genetic algorithm for a class project in python.  The algorithm works perfectly, but I want to create an image of the tree, rather than just a simple text output.  I have written a function that performs well for trees up to about 4 levels.  Above that, the display doesn't work well, and there ends up with too much blank space. I know why, but it might take me too long to come up with a better solution.

Does anyone know if there exists a function to create a compact non-binary tree display?  I'm looking for one that adjusts each branch so there isn't a ton of blank space between them, given that a lot of the branch depths are un-even. I've found a lot of binary tree display functions, but that doesn't work because some of my nodes have 3 children.

You can see it working well and not working well in the images.

Decent looking tree:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j2BQjanTDgvzttedUyhxnbWhkXuQwyaG/view?usp=sharing

Not so great tree (too much blank space):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gh90e3JvAeCB_U2NhvvouZulM4CVQ8ZH/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/).
In particular, the `dot` layout generator should be a good match for your needs.

You may also find the [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs) [drawing](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) module helpful.